# Meaning of "allocation size" in allocation tracker

Tags: android, eclipse

I am looking at the output of the allocation tracker from my app and am confused about the meaning of "allocation size". What are the units?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bytes. From [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html):

> Click on an object type in the list to see a bar graph that shows the
>   number of objects allocated for a particular memory size in **bytes**.

Comment: but only `Viewing heap usage for a process` mentions bytes. The post is about the `Allocation Size` in `Allocation Tracker`. I can understand that the leap is not a big one. But its still not an exact reference. Sorry for giving you a hard time when you are trying to help people. I just need to know from an authoritative reference.